# Any way to make dict passed to URL express in regexp in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Say, I have a dict

```
URLS = {'admin' : '/admin/(.*)'}
```

and if I do so

```
application = ([
(r(URLS['admin']), AdminPage)
], debug=True)
```

google app engine will raise an error

```
NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

I really really need to pass dictionary described in regexp to URL map for making my code more module.

What should I do to make it work?

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The 'r' is a string prefix to escape some sequences for regular expression. It is not a function.
http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

```
URLS = {'admin' : r'/admin/(.*)'}

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
(URLS['admin'], AdminPage)
], debug=True)
```

The "webapp.WSGIApplication" will compile these strings to regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`re.compile`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-contents) is what you are looking for.

Comment: the `r` stands for raw, not regexp. It doesn't create regular expressions, is just lets you get away with not using the dreaded quadruple backslashes you need in regular python strings.